# Evitar campos sin datos en csv

Tags: python, csv

por favor me pueden ayudar con este problema.

yo cree un documento csv que tiene de headers = ["Horas","L" ,"M" ,"W" ,"J", "V" ]
cuando yo leo el documento con DictReader me lo trae de esta manera:

`{'Horas': '20:00', 'L': '', 'M': '', 'W': '', 'J': '', 'V': 'Tutoria Jhoiner'}`

y a mi me gustaria que me lo diera así:

`{'Horas': '20:00', 'V': 'Tutoria Jhoiner'}`

¿Qué puedo hacer para evitar que me traiga los campos que no tienen datos?

gracias

Comment: En estricto rigor, una cadena vacía es un dato (contiene información). Por ejemplo, `segundo_nombre=''` me dice que la persona **no** tiene segundo nombre. Si quisiera decir que **no** tengo información sobre el segundo nombre (no sé cual es o si lo tiene o no), escribiría `segundo_nombre = None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una manera sencilla de hacerlo es crear un nuevo diccionario, copiando los valores que:

- No sean cadenas (int, float, otros ...), o que
- Sean cadenas de largo 1 o superior.

Hay que crear un nuevo diccionario, ya que no puedes eliminar elementos mientras lo recorres.

Usamos lo siguiente: `isinstance(valor, str)` retorna `True` si `valor` es una cadena.

Para preguntar por el largo, basta escribir el nombre de la cadena. El resultado será `True` si la cadena es de largo 1 o superior.

Código:

```
dic = {'Horas': '20:00', 'L': '', 'M': '', 'W': '', 'J': '', 'V': 'Tutoria Jhoiner'}
dic_limpio = {}
for k, v in dic.items():
    if not isinstance(v, str) or v:
        dic_limpio[k] = v

print(dic_limpio)
```

Produce:

```
{'Horas': '20:00', 'V': 'Tutoria Jhoiner'}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @CandidMoe

Answer (score 1):

Filtrando por [comprensión de diccionarios](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
dic = {c:v for (c,v) in dic.items() if v != ''}
```

genera el diccionario con todas las claves `c` y valores `v` al recorrer el original con `dic.items()` si cumplen con que `v` no sea una cadena vacía.

> o simplemente la condición `if v` si querés sacar cualquier *falsy* (ceros por ejemplo)